# How to remove circular reference resulting from dependency injection in my MVC Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

My solution contains 3 projects -

`Project A` - which is the startup project

`Project B` - which containers interfaces, providers, helpers and implementations that are injected in `Project A`

`Project C` - which is responsible for resolving IoC using Autofac.

`Project A` contains a reference to `Project B` since it requires the interfaces in there. `Project C` contains a reference to `Project A`.

I am now trying to implement a new interface which needs to use the models defined in `Project A`. If I create the interface in `Project B` this results in circular reference since `Project A` already references `Project B` so `Project B` cannot reference `Project A` for using the model.

If I create the interface in `Project A` then I cannot register it without referencing `Project A` from `Project C` because circular again.

Where do I create and implement this interface without causing a circular reference. The interface is a kind of an authentication manager provider. I could just create a function for doing the stuff within my Controller but that is very untidy.

Comment: Why does `B` need a reference to `A`?  I'm assuming `B` is your application code, and since `A` is your main code, `B` should not be dependent upon `A`.  Without knowing why `B` needs to know of `A`'s models, my only suggestion is not to do that.

Comment: `B` will require a reference to `A` if I try to create the interface in `B` because the interface makes use of the models defined in `A`

Comment: These are view-models you're talking about?

Comment: yes, these are the view models.

Comment: My recommendation is still the same then, give `B` its own models that are separate from `A`, and then translate them to `A`'s model inside of `A`'s project if you need to.  Likely the format of the two models will be different, and it would be best to not couple the concept of MVC models into `B`'s project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the models from Project A to Project B and from your description, it looks like that is a common layer anyway.

So then your new interface can be created in Project B and it won't have to access Project A to access those models.

Comment: But aren't the models for an MVC application always in the primary/startup project?

Comment: The models can be put anywhere. MVC by conventions looks for views/controllers in the main project (even that can be changed). But in your case, it makes sense to move out the models, since they are a common artifact. You can also create core/domain models in Project B and map those to View Models in Project A. In doing so, you need to write those mappers that map from domain -> view model or you can use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to do convention based mapping.

Comment: Well for now I have moved the Models to `B` and it seems to work. Not sure if this is best practice. Might look into Automapper and a core Model project.
(Gonna wait a while before I mark your answer as the solution.)

Comment: I use domain/core models in common layer and ViewModels in my MVC project. This is the preferred way but it also adds to complexity (2 things to maintain, mappers etc.). As you project grows and as those models start to deviate more from your common structure, consider investing in that extra effort (of creating View Models and mappers).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a flow in your architecture.

Are you able to extract the Interfaces in another project (who will be referenced in all project, but wont reference the others) and to have nothing else in it (so we won't be tempted to reference something else)?

When doing injection, I always seperate the interfaces projects from the implementations ones... To many ways to mixe them up.